# How to prevent a spinner dropdown menu from closing after clicking an item?

Tags: android, android-spinner

I would like to keep the spinner dropdown menu open after an item has been clicked.

Its default behavior is to close when an item has been selected. Instead, I want it to stay open to allow the different items to be clicked multiple times without closing the spinner.

```
private Spinner spinner_simple;
spinner_simple = findViewById(R.id.spinner_simple);

final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter_simple = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, 0){

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        }
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        }
        return view;
    }

};

adapter_simple.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner_simple.setAdapter(adapter_simple);

spinner_simple.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        // Note: When an item has been clicked, don't refresh the spinner.
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) { 
    }

});
```

I don't know whether there is a particular onClick/onSelection listener which can be overridden to prevent the spinner from closing.

Most questions I have read discuss how to refresh or close/open the spinner dynamically, but I would like it to stay open, and make it closable by selecting the first item or clicking outside its body while active.

Comment: You should probably think about using a different UI component, probably a custom Dialog for things like. Or is there any specification that you have to use a spinner?

Comment: @glm9637 Well, I don't have to use a spinner, it's just that allowing clicks on items without closing the dropdown menu would be enough for what I'm trying to do. Is there a way to design a custom dialog like a spinner?

Answer (score 2):

If it helps you can extend `ArrayAdapter` and override `areAllItemsEnabled(): Boolean` to return false. This will prevent the dropdown from being closed on click.

Also, if you want to keep the click effects, you can override `getDropDownView()` to inflate a custom layout and add this to the root view of your custom layout:

```
android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true"
```

The downside is that `AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener` listeners won't be triggered when an item is clicked. A workaround is to add a click listener to the view inflated on getDropDownView()

Answer (score 1):

You could extend the Spinner class and override the PerformClick() method in a way that upon selecting an item, the spinner does not close. 
For eg.:

```
        public override bool PerformClick()
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Context);
        //builder.SetItems(_items, this); or builder.SetMultiChoiceItems(_items, _selection, this);
        builder.SetPositiveButton("OK", delegate { builder.Dispose(); });
        builder.Show();
        return true;
    }
```